How to load TradingView URL in Jetpack Compose WebView?
I am working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose, and I need to display a TradingView chart within a WebView. However, I'm encountering an issue where the TradingView URL does not load in the Jetpack Compose WebView, while other URLs load without any problems. Interestingly, the TradingView URL works fine when used in  XML-based project.
item {
                val symbol = selectedCoin?.symbol
                val url =
                    "https://s.tradingview.com/widgetembed/?frameElementId=tradingview_76d87&symbol=${symbol}USD&interval=D&hidesidetoolbar=1&hidetoptoolbar=1&symboledit=1&saveimage=1&toolbarbg=F1F3F6&studies=[]&hideideas=1&theme=Dark&style=1&timezone=Etc/UTC&studies_overrides={}&overrides={}&enabled_features=[]&disabled_features=[]&locale=en&utmsource=coinmarketcap.com&utm_medium=widget&utm_campaign=chart&utm_term=BTCUSDT"
                TradingChartWebView(url = url)
            }

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun TradingChartWebView(url: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            WebView(context).apply {
                settings.apply {
                    javaScriptEnabled = true
                    domStorageEnabled = true
                    loadWithOverviewMode = true
                    useWideViewPort = true
                    cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
                    mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                    userAgentString =
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
                }

                webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

                webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                        Log.d("WebView", "Page started loading: $url")
                    }

                    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                        Log.d("WebView", "Page finished loading: $url")
                    }

                    override fun onReceivedError(
                        view: WebView?,
                        request: WebResourceRequest?,
                        error: WebResourceError?
                    ) {
                        Log.e("WebView", "Error loading page: ${error?.description}")
                    }
                }


                loadUrl(url)
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(400.dp)
    )
}


Here I am trying to show the chart of the cryptocurrency with the tradingview url, but I get a blank screen like this

I tried the codes I shared above and I did not get a webview graphic. I expect a webview chart to appear.

Did you try inspecting the webview and seeing if there are any errors?

@tomerpacific I did and didn't see any errors
